# Logic in making sure a int variable doesnt exceed 0

Tags: java

Okay i know this may be simple but i am struggling with it for some reason.

What i am trying to do is not allow a user's score to go into the negative.

For example, a user score is 10..Then they get a -11. instead of the int going to -1 i would like for it to just go to 0. Now, ive came up with this code so far.

```
  hitCount -=10;

  if(hitCount <= 0){

     hitCount = 0;

      }else{

     hitCount -=10;
        }
```

As you see i deduct -10 initially but run a check to make sure the number isnt negative, and if it is we set it to 0. The only problem is, when the  hitCount is 11 and then - 10. it subtracts to -9 for some reason.

I just want it to simply go to 0 and not beyond that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Vote to close: this could easily be solved by stepping through the code in a debugger.

Comment: Why you subtract the hitCount at the begining of the code? It's not just check if it is less than zero??

Comment: You should have answered man. lol

Comment: This account must be hacked. How do you have a reputation of 2,797 and ask such a question?

Comment: And i see where i made the mistake at.

Comment: Sorry guys i will delete this question, one of my friends posted this on my account 0__0

Comment: Everyone please vote to close this ridiculous question

Answer (score 5):

```
hitCount = Math.max(0, hitCount-10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
hitCount -= 10;
if(hitCount < 0)
{
    hitCount = 0;
}
```

The error arises because if hit count is 11, you subtract 10, and then it's 1. The else clause then fires, and subtracts 10 again. That's your error, **remove the else clause**.